# Core data and large files downloads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I'm storing some PDFs into a `NSManagedObject` property of type `NSData`. I've set "Use external storage" for the property and it works quite well. The problem I have is, when the PDF is really large, the app crashes because it runs out of memory. Is there a way to save the data chunk by chunk directly to disk? I already use `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` but even so, I have to keep the data into memory until the full download is finished (and only then I can call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`) to fault the property and release my memory. Of course for large docs, that's to late, it crashes way before I have the chance to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if I were in your position, I would obtain the `NSInputStream` that is the incoming PDF file and use an `NSOutputStream` to write it directly to disk.

As for core data, I do not think it is appropriate to use for files that you don't intend to fault in to memory completely; Apple doesn't give us an option to get an NSInputStream from the file saved to disk via core data (that I'm aware of anyway). In that case, I would just save the location of the file in core data, and after faulting in that file path, creating an `NSInputStream` from that saved path.

It's a bit lower in abstraction than most developers prefer to be, but it's better to be in control of anything that has potential of causing out of memory crashes.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? If I'm wrong, please someone correct me.